# Move table from MS SQL straight in to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Up till now I have used sqlcmd to dump out the information I need to csv ,in to a samba share then have MySQL import this in the where it is then needed. I am wondering if I can cut out a step and go straight from MSSQl in to MySQL directly, 
Please note MySQL is on Debian not windows.
I have done some research and cannot find anything remotely close to what I want. Assuming this is because it’s cross platform

Comment: Have you looked at sql server replication? It can do this from sql server to mysql with no problems.

Comment: Or you could create a linked server from MSSQL to the MySQL and you could create the table in MySQL and then use your linked server connection to insert all values from MSSQL table into the MySQL table, documentation (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/), but @SeanLange's comment is probably the better solution.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use SSIS?   I have no idea what the limitations of Debian are.

Comment: Thank you ! didnt know this could happen. Always learning !!! :-)